# What happens if i send html over tcp without using the http protocol?

Tags: networking, http, tcp

Will the html be delivered properly to the browser, or will it lack formatting? Will it get delivered at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean "without including HTTP response headers", as the browser sends a HTTP request anyway.

It will actually work, since HTTP/0.9 did not have any headers – clients sent a single `GET /path` line for a request, and the server just dumped the file in return.

So if the server response doesn't start with `HTTP/1`, the client will assume it's talking to a HTTP/0.9 server and that the entire response is a `text/html` page.